# DynamoDB Modeling. Fetch Items once for each user

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I need to design a table (I'm newbie in DynamoDB) with these entities:

1. "Question".

   - ID (int)
   - Order (int)
   - IsPublished (bool)
   - Data (some json)
2. "User"

   - ID (int)
   - Data (some json)
3. "QuestionResult"

   - UserID (int)
   - QuestionID (int)
   - Result (some json)

QuestionResult table is being populated after user passes question. It's going to grow.

The main query pattern is:

I need to fetch f.e. 10 questions from "Question" table ordered by Order and IsPublished is true. And the most important - only those "Question" items the given User has **never answered before**. In other words - fetch from Questions **excluding QuestionID exists in QuestionResult for particular UserID**

Every time client asks for new set of questions - they should be new to him.

Any ideas how to organize such DB in efficient way? Taking into account QuestionResult table will rapidly grow with number of users and passed questions.

Comment: What does Order (int) signify in Question table?

Comment: It's a column to sort the output. I need my questions sequence to be ordered

Comment: I think this query pattern is too complex to handle efficiently in DynamoDB. You may want to consider a relational database, which at some point will limit your scalability. Chances are then you'll understand more about the access pattern and can design/reframe it in a way that it may be solved in DynamoDB.